# highstock: how to change color in areaspline when series intersect sma

Tags: highcharts

good morning guys,
I need your help for a problem that I can not solve.
I need to highlight the intersections between a simple data series and the related moving average. 
The data of the moving average are automatically generated by HighStock and are not calculated by me (otherwise I would have almost solved the problem!).

If it is not possible to graphically highlight with different colors every time the series is above or below the moving average 
I would like to calculate the difference between the two series (in this way I could draw a single line around the zero value with negative red values and values green positive for example).

After numerous researches I have not yet solved my problem. I must say that the documentation of HighChart / HighStock is very complete but it is mainly for professionals.
Thanks for your help!

[This is what I need (look at the picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkn33.png)

```
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    title: { text: 'Relative Strenght' },
    navigator: { enabled: false },
    series: [
        {
            id: 'forza-rel',
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Rel. Str.',
            data: forza_relativa,
        }, 
        {
            name: 'M.A. 5',
            type: 'sma',
            linkedTo: 'forza-rel',
            color:'#FF0000',
            dashStyle: 'line',
            marker: { enabled: false },
            params: { period: 5 }
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to highlight the intersections between a simple data series and
>   the related moving average.

It can be done, however, it requires a lot of custom code and it's a bit tricky.

> I would like to calculate the difference between the two series

This can be done easily. SMA is just another series, so you have to loop through SMA series data and make a difference between its data and a basic series data. Than use [series.setData()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) method to update the third series with calculated values (areasplie for example).

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/indicators.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  chart: {
    height: 500,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          series = chart.series,
          data = [],
          offset,
          diff,
          i;

        offset = series[0].xData.length - series[1].xData.length;

        for (i = 0; i < series[1].xData.length; i++) {
          diff = series[0].yData[i + offset] - series[1].yData[i];
          data.push({
            x: series[1].xData[i],
            y: diff
          });
        }

        chart.series[2].setData(data);
      }
    }
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0
  },

  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },

  yAxis: [{
    height: '60%',
    top: '0%',
    id: '0'
  }, {
    height: '36%',
    top: '62%',
    id: '1'
  }],

  series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    id: 'aapl',
    name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
    data: data,
    yAxis: '0'
  }, {
    type: 'sma',
    linkedTo: 'aapl',
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: '0'
  }, {
    type: 'areaspline',
    yAxis: '1',
    color: 'green',
    negativeColor: 'red',
    data: []
  }]
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/863n241h/3/

Comment: Hello Chmiel, thanks for your answer, it's really a great solution! It work for me!

Comment: You're welcome. If you find this answer correct and helpful, please upvote.

Comment: I'm sorry but stackoverflow doesn't accept my vote. Of corse it's the right answer but i can't vote because of my reputation ( i still have less then 15 reputation). Sorry

Comment: It's OK now! Thanks a lot!